# Finding the particular integral of $\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}\sin ax$

Tags: differential-equations

I have come across this method for finding the particular integral of $\frac{1}{f(D)}\sin ax$ where $f(-a^2)=0$ as $x\frac{1}{f'(D)}\sin ax$ which gives the same result.  However I am wondering if this is a standard result and how do we arrive at this result. We can use this for Partial Differential Equations as well. $\frac{1}{f(D,D')}\sin(ax+by)$ where $f(a,b)=0$ as $x\frac{1}{f'(D)}\sin(ax+by)$

Here for ODE $D$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $F(D)$ will be a function of derivatives. For eg - $D^2-3D-2$ where $D^n$ is $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$.

Similarly for PDE $D$ means $\frac{dx}{dz}$ and $D'$ means $\frac{dy}{dz}$. For eg - $D^2D'-3DD'^2-2D'^3$ where $D^n$ is $\frac{d^nx}{dz^n}$ and $D'^n$ is $\frac{d^ny}{dz^n}$.

Comment: what is denoted by $D$?

Comment: And what is $f(D)$. It can not be univariate and at the same time bivariate.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: there is an inconsistency in the notation: you define $f$ to be a function of $D$, not of $D^2$, so instead of $f(-a^2)=0$ you need $f(ia)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

These identities are easiest to understand if instead of $\sin ax$ we take $e^{iax}$.
We wish to determine the function $J(x)$ ("particular integral") such that $f(D)J(x)=e^{iax}$, with $D=d/dx$ the differential operator.

Since $De^{iax}=ia e^{iax}$, we have $J(x)=\frac{1}{f(ia)}e^{iax}$ if $f(ia)\neq 0$.

If instead $f(ia)=0$ while $f'(ia)\neq 0$, we can still evaluate $J$ by noting the identity$^\ast$
$$f(D)\bigl(e^{iax}x\bigr)=f'(ia)e^{iax}\Rightarrow J(x)= \frac{1}{f'(ia)}e^{iax}x$$

$^\ast$ for a proof of this identity, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622057/87355

---

Test that $f(D)J(x)=e^{iax}$, for the example in the title of the OP, $f(D)=D^2+a^2$:
$$f(D)J(x)=(D^2+a^2)\frac{1}{f'(ia)}e^{iax}x=\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+a^2\right)\frac{1}{2ia}e^{iax}x=e^{iax}.$$